# SQL Self Join Duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I must do a query with the following columns

| ID | Date | Amount | Id_transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/01/2022 | 456 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/01/2022 | 845 | 3 |
| 1 | 2/01/2022 | 342 | 632 |
| 1 | 2/01/2022 | 643 | 636 |
| 1 | 1/03/2022 | 707 | 16 |
| 1 | 1/03/2022 | 8735 | 17 |

I take amount of the past 2 days and do a `sum()` with a `self join`. My problem is, when I do the above, the output rows get duplicated. It is impossible!

With a `distinct` modifier it works, but in my case I can't use it.

My code, as of now:

```
select a."ID" , a."Date" , sum(b."Amount") 
from data a
left join data b on a."ID" = b."ID"
where a."Date" - b."Date" < 2
group by a."ID" , a."Date"
order by a."ID" , a."Date" asc;
```

Comment: It was fun to edit your question. Still, you'd be better post sample data and expected output.

Comment: you right I'm new on this ;c hahaha , im going to improve it

Comment: Please attach the output you desired too :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why the self-join? Are you trying maybe to compare a day's sum with the sum two days before? For this you would simply use `LAG`. (A column called ID should contain unique values, thus uniquely identifying a row in the table as its name suggests, by the way.)

Comment: Without the original data, it is impossible to say anything here.

Comment: I mean, if you run your query on your shared sample data, it will just give out the correct output, that's the reason why you're getting these comments. Please share some relevant sample data. @CariCambiante

Comment: You updated post with sample data, good. Now, for better understanding, please provide expected output. It is a table, that you want to see as a result of your successful query. See this [what others expect to see on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).